# Цикл по вложенным словарям и спискам

Tags: python, python-3.x

пытаюсь сделать текстовый квест примерно из вот такого кода:

```
{"Location_1": ["Enemy10", {"Location_2": ["Enemy15",{"Location_10": [{"Exit": "Win"}]}]}]}
```

По факту словарь больше и более разветвлен, находится в отдельном json файле.
Реализация должна заключаться в том, что нужно выбирать локации(ключ словаря), заходить в них, внутри будут враги, последние числа названий которых нужно суммировать, и также другие локации.
Подскажите, какая конструкция должна быть у цикла по таким разветвлениям. Допустим, с помощью цикла фор попадаю в значения первой локации, и как далее реализовывать выбор элементов и последующие проходы в локации не соображу
Более подробные правила:

На прохождение дается 100000 секунд.
Цель - за отведенное время найти выход

По мере прохождения вглубь происходит затопление, поэтому
в каждую локацию можно попасть только один раз,
и выйти обратно нельзя (то есть двигаться можно только вперед).

Чтобы открыть выход и выбраться, нужно иметь не менее 300 очков опыта.
Если до открытия время заканчивается - гг умирает, а игра начинается заново.
Карта это json-файл. Локации в лабиринте описывается объектами,
в которых находится единственный ключ с названием, соответствующем формату "Location_nm_tm",
где N - номер локации, а T - это время,
которое необходимо для перехода. Например, если игрок заходит в локацию "Location_8_1000",
то он тратит на это 1000 секунд.
По ключу находится список, содержащий строки с врагами а также другие локации.
Описание врага представляет собой строку в формате "enemy_ex_tm", где K - количество опыта,
которое получает игрок, уничтожив врага, а M - это время,
которое потратит игрок для уничтожения врага.
Например, уничтожив монстра "Boss_exp10_tm20", игрок потратит 20 секунд и получит 10 единиц опыта.
Нужный путь только один.
При каждом ходе игрока скрипт должен запоминать в csv файл следующую информацию:

- текущую локацию
- текущий опыт
- текущие дату и время

Comment: У вас внутри словаря список, где во втором элементе словарь, в котором опять список..

Comment: у словарей ключ - название локации, список - значение, в котором есть враги и словари с другими локациями

Comment: а задача - найти выигрышную стратегию или просто реагировать на выбор пользователя?

Comment: готовый код будет давать возможность игроку пройти игру в случае удачного выбора, при этом все действия будут записываться, и получится своего рода текстовый файл с описанием всего что происходило от выборов игрока до воскрешений после смерти, рассказ о проделанном прохождении

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я только для удобства разделил цифры и названия, чтобы удобно было вычленять, но алгоритм можно любой сделать, например просто отрезать `Enemy` (если он присутствует в слове)

```
data = {"Location_1": ["Enemy_10", {"Location_2": ["Enemy_15",{"Location_10": [{"Exit": "Win"}]}]}]}


def analyze_object(object):
    count = 0

    # если объект - словарь, то проанализировать все значения словаря по ключу
    if isinstance(object, dict):
        for key in object:
            count += analyze_object(object[key])

    # если объект - список, то проанализировать все элементы списка
    if isinstance(object, list):
        for element in object:
            count += analyze_object(element)

    # если объект - строка, то вычленить числа
    if isinstance(object, str):
        word = object.split('_')
        if len(word) == 2:
            count += int(word[1])

    return count


print(analyze_object(data))
```

Comment: спасибо за код, попробую на основе его сделать под свою задачу. Но он быстро проходится по всем элементам, а мне не столько подсчитать все нужно, сколько реализовать переходы. Допустим: вы находитесь на локации 1, перед вами локация 2 и локация 3, что выберите? Вы выбрали 3, вы внутри. Перед вами враг с 20 опыта и локация 4, что выберете и т.д.

Comment: т.е. со всеми врагами сражения необязательны, нужно по итогу дойдя до конца иметь нужное количество опыта

Comment: ну вы это можете сделать просто добавив нужные проверки под `for` в которых элементы находятся, но вообще ваше представление локаций порочно, поскольку не позволяет делать объединения типа локация1 - локация2 - локация3 - локация1, по идее вам нужен список со всеми локациями, а в каждой локации список с названиями локаций которые к ней присоединяются - и вот с таким представлением уже удобно обходить локации как связанные списки

Comment: по заданию локации не зациклены, если не сделать правильный выбор, то игра будет проиграна. В условиях у локаций тоже есть свои временные очки, и если их будет больше чем нужно, то значит "было потрачено слишком много времени и персонаж не успел выбраться"

Comment: и возвращаться из локации наверх нельзя? тогда более подробно изложите задачу

Comment: добавил в вопросе полное описание